# Will password protected user accounts in XP Pro provide sufficient security for Remote Desktop over internet?

Tags: windows-xp, security, remote-desktop

Will password protected user accounts in XP Pro provide sufficient security for Remote Desktop over internet?

Comment: What exactly are you worried about?

Comment: Someone else logging in, or someone else intercepting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default windows xp can allow RDC with little to none encryption to connect (which poses a security risk). change it by:

Run `"%SystemRoot%\system32\gpedit.msc /s"`

Go through `Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | Terminal Services | Encryption and Security.`

Set `"Set client connection encryption level"` to `"Enabled"` and `"High Level"`

keylogging is more of a concern, and a relatively difficult thing to prevent when you are in an uncontrolled environment though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would be willing to use RDP on an unsecured connection. I would suggest you investigate VPN solutions and RDP though them. Or look at something like TeamViewer.

Comment: What is at risk with using RDP on an unsecured connection?  Are the usernames and passwords sent as clear text?

Comment: no unless you are using really old RDP clients. modern RDP clients support encryption (128-bit encryption, using the RC4 encryption algorithm, as of Version 6)